# How to filter antd table w/o using filterDropdown?

Tags: reactjs, filter, antd

I've been trying to figure out filtering of antd table all day. My design is to have a visible filter in the title:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvEDA.png)

I don't want the pop-up as in all the examples.  So the question is, is it possible to just set filter properties?

I took the standard example and made just the Address filterable

https://codepen.io/jabberwo/pen/OJJyzLg?editors=0011

But when I remove the filterDropdown (where is the documentation on what the function input arguments are?!) and instead set the filterValue to text in state updated by the onChange of an input as in

https://codepen.io/jabberwo/pen/XWWmVKL?editors=0011

I get a really weird error on line 975 of antd/es/table/Table.js

```
Uncaught TypeError: values.some is not a function
    at VM1051 vendors~main.3a264a9707764ceadc39.bundle.js:53640
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
```

This is thrown because I have filteredValue and onFilter set.  If I don't set one of them I don't get the error -- but I also don't get any filtering. From the doc this looks like what I'm supposed to do. Even a simple

```
onFilter: () => true
```

will throw so it's not the filtering code, but this mysterious values.some that is supposed to be defined.

thanks,
Jab

Answer (score 3):

OMG 3-4 hours wasted not realizing filteredValue has to be an array of strings!

```
filteredValue: [this.state.alertFilter.toLowerCase()],
onFilter: (value, record) =>
           record.alertName
              .toString()
              .toLowerCase()
              .includes(this.state.alertFilter.toLowerCase()),
```

Yes, the doc does say that, it just didn't click, didn't see it or something to that effect.

Putting the answer up here for the next developer using google to find help...